# JScrollPane disappearing on resize

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have a content part with a vertical scroll bar, that is part of a window. The exact classes are:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane1;
JEditorPane editorPaneContent;
JPanel contentPanel;

scrollPane1.setViewportView(editorPaneContent);
contentPanel.add(scrollPane1, CC.xy(1, 1));
```

The scrollbar should not always be visible, if the content is small, then it should not appear. (So far it works.)

However if the content is large, and the scrollbar appears, resizing the main window (horizontally) will sometimes make the scrollbar disappear. Curious, that one resize makes it disappear, another resize makes it appear again. Disappear-appear-disappear in strict order. **How can I force the scrollbar, to appear (only when it is needed by the length of the content) even after resizing the main window?**

Thanks for the help, Sziro.

Comment: Try to create a running example code of your problem, and show us.

Comment: `How can I force the scrollbar, to appear (only when it is needed by the length of the content) even after resizing the main window?` - this is the default behaviour, assuming you have added the scroll pane to the CENTER of the BorderLayout of the frame. However your code is using a content panel with a funny constraint when you add the scroll pane to the panel. So the problem is probably with the layout manager that you are using on your contentPanel.

Comment: CC is com.jgoodies.forms.factories.CC, that is used for layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollPane1.setVertivalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

That should help